# Rails + Redis + Sidekiq error: IO::EAGAINWaitReadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm getting random `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` sometimes when executing a job from `Sidekiq` with `redis` as caching service.

`redis` and `sidekiq` are running on the same server. I'm also getting this issue sometimes when I try to get a value from `Rails.cache`.

Any idea ?

PS: No need to provide code here as it makes no sense.

### EDIT

#### Answer found

After some research and reading more about `redis`, here's what I found: https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Using `allkeys-lru` really did the Job here, and we're no longer receiving timeouts due to the keys being deleted when they're not used.

#### How to fix

open the redis-cli:

```
redis-cli
```

Now, in the cli

```
CONFIG SET maxmemory 8G
CONFIG SET maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

You can change the `8G` memory to whatever you want.

Comment: Did you have a look at these? https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2935, https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4086

Comment: @erosenin yes I did; I'm testing with `jemalloc` right now. Till now I have no errors. If this continues like this for at least 7 more days, I'll post the solution here :-) Thanks.

Comment: @erosenin I've posted my answer; `jemalloc` wasn't the solution and we were still getting timeouts